# Cordova SQLite not returning rows after query

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova app and I'm using cordova-sqlite-storage plugin

My query is very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM clients;
```

This is the Javascript code:

```
  ctx.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM cards;", [], function(tx, rs) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(rs));
            onSuccess(rs);
        }, function(tx, error) {
            onfail();
        });
    });
```

the `rs` doesn't contain the row data, the alert shows:

```
{"rows":{"length":1},"rowsAffected":0}
```

so I have 1 row somewhere but it's not returning it

what I'm missing here?

Comment: What is actually in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get back data you need to use rs.rows.item(0).*fieldname*

try alert (rs.rows.item(0));

Comment: I was doing rs.rows[0] instead of rs.rows.item(0)